# Coleman ct100u engine, no start

Tags: starting, carburetor, timing, valve-timing, engine-start

Verified igniton system is good, cleaned and gapped plug. The engine is is essentially pushing out gas from the carb side and not wanting to start, I don’t know what else to add I’m not really familiar with these types of engines...

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1thatMVo_cvM4uls0MGgeYSgRWA3CkZlN

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NhudiSbO1-zaorZKSbcYVKcIN4X5hHe7

Hopefully these can help, I’m thinking the timing is off somehow (it was rattling really bad before and then just stopped starting. I can turn the engine over fine like there’s nothing hitting, but it does that gas through the carb thing (killswitch was in on position for spark to occur)

Comment: Is this a generator? Oh, it's a mini-bike or two wheeled vehicle with a motor attached. With everything hooked up (spark/gas), does it try to fire at all?

Comment: No it just blows out through the carb when I pull start it, I have no clue what that could mean

Comment: It could be flooded. Your carb might be pushing too much fuel, either due to a bad float (float doesn't float), or the needle/seat valve is stuck open. I'm not sure what the first picture is of? Is this part of the carburetor?

Comment: It’s when you take that OHV cap off, that’s the underside of it, ive no clue how it got dinged up there

Comment: I took apart the whole thing and put it back together (reset cam and valves), it turns over nice and easy now but it’s just not starting still, gonna try replace spark plug tmrw

Comment: when I say whole thing I mean the engine itself not the carb or exhaust or igniton etc